# CNAME already taken

Tags: github, web, github-pages, cname

Today I created a repository with CNAME "www.mywebsite.com" with some source files e.g (index.html) etc and everything works like a charm... my all source files are available on my custom domain name.

Then I deleted my account also the repository that contains the CNAME file "www.mywebsite.com" and few hours later I created a new account and wanted to create a new repository with same CNAME "www.mywebsite.com" that I previous used on my old account, when I created a new CNAME file that contains my previous website URL "www.mywebsite.com" I get an automated message that this CNAME is already taken-

But I deleted my old account with a repository that contains CNAME file "www.mywebsite.com" now why am i receiving this message that your CNAME is already taken?

So,

Hope you understand what I'm trying to say... what should I do now ?

Thanks so much and waiting for your response.

Comment: [Patience, young grasshopper](http://maryhess.com/patience-young-grasshopper/).  Wait overnight, and see if the CNAME is still in use.  DNS changes can take 6, 12 or more hours to propagate.  PS: You're cure you DELETED the old cname file and PUSHED your change before you deleted your account, correct?

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, i just deleted my account not repo, so it's mean when i deleted my account the repo is automatically deleted and CNAME file too. right?

Comment: did you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, It's solved.